# lms400 interfacing for robotic pick and place

Tags: ros, sicklms

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
Im relatively new to ROS and am trying to integrate a SICK LMS400 to create a 3d point cloud. The application is for identification of a set of object keypoints for a robotic pick and place application. My approach is to broadly create a 3D point cloud (using tf or pcl library) after interfacing with the LMS400, then filter ( using height as the condition) the points to obtain keypoints ( a smaller relevant point cloud), and then send these points through the ros_opcua_communication package to a PLC.
My first question: Does this approach make sense? (im trying to avoid the corresponding object mapping approach)

Second:
Ive gone through the ROS packages and unfortunately couldn't find the SICK LMS400 package. It seems it was earlier on sourceforge through TUM, but now its unavailable.
Would anyone have the package with them? or if you can direct me to a location for it..
Will that work on Ubuntu Kinetic?

Thanks in advance!
Srivatsa

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253719/lms400-interfacing-for-robotic-pick-and-place/) by [srivatsamahesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/29248/srivatsamahesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I found the SICK LMS400 package at:

https://sourceforge.net/p/tum-ros-pkg/code/HEAD/tree/drivers/

works really well

---

Originally posted by [srivatsamahesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/29248/srivatsamahesh/) with karma: 16 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0